# Sequelize code not showing all data in the result, but does show in the sql result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code:

```
const click_tracking = await ClickTrackingModel.findAndCountAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: AppModel,
                    attributes: [],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: DomainModel,
                            attributes: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    model: CountryModel,
                    attributes: []
                }
            ],
            attributes: [
                "position",
                [sequelize.literal('DATE_FORMAT(`clicks_tracking`.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%m:%s")'), 'created_at'],
                [sequelize.literal('`app`.name'), 'app_name'],
                [sequelize.literal('`app->domain`.domain'), 'domain'],
                [sequelize.literal('`country`.name'), 'country']
            ],
            order: [
                ['created_at', 'DESC']
            ]
        });
```

which yields this query:

```
SELECT
    `clicks_tracking`.`id`,
    `clicks_tracking`.`position`,
    DATE_FORMAT (`clicks_tracking`.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%m:%s") AS `created_at`,
    `app`.name AS `app_name`,
    `app->domain`.domain AS `domain`,
    `country`.name AS `country`
FROM
    `clicks_tracking` AS `clicks_tracking`
    INNER JOIN `apps` AS `app` ON `clicks_tracking`.`app_id` = `app`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `domains` AS `app->domain` ON `app`.`domain_id` = `app->domain`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `countries` AS `country` ON `clicks_tracking`.`country_id` = `country`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `created_at` DESC
```

and although I do see the correct `country` column in the sql results, it doesn't appear in the response `json` from `sequelize`:

```
[{
    "position": 1,
    "created_at": "29-08-2023 16:08:59",
    "app_name": "Test Yaniv App",
    "domain": "testtal123.xyz"
 }, 
 {
    "position": 1,
    "created_at": "29-08-2023 16:08:21",
    "app_name": "Test Yaniv App",
    "domain": "testtal123.xyz"
}]
```

and I have no idea why... Would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the issue:

in my literal attributes I set aliases, but they were the same names as the singular join names as well (`country`,`domain` etc). I just changed the aliases to `country_name`, `domain_name`, that did the trick.

Comment: For some reason it won't let me, says I have to wait 23 hours...